# How do I run puppet agent inside a docker container to build it out. How do I achieve this?

Tags: apache, docker

If I run a docker container with `CMD["/use/sbin/ssh", "-D"]`, I can have them running daemonized, which is good. 
Then, I want to run puppet agent too, to build our said container as say an apache server.

Is it possible to do this and then expose the apache server?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to run puppet standalone rather than as an agent? What happens when you spin up multiple instances of your container? Each would attempt to connect to the puppet master as the same client, wouldn't it?

Comment: I solved the issue by using supervisord as the daemon rather than sshd.

Comment: Could you post your solution or at least the little example?

Comment: Official supervisor tutorial : https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Would be nice if you self answered your question with the solution.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor A little late. But puppet agent typically uses the `fqdn` as the `certname` for the agent. So `docker` hostnames are typically all unique based on the `id` of the container. So theoretically running the agent should work. untested though.

Comment: using supervisor is ok, but I suggest build your image with apache. exposing a port of running container is not possible at present.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. We use ENTRYPOINT docker file instruction as described here: https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint. Using it you can run puppet agent and other services in background before instruction from CMD or command passed via docker run.